# Can I add a Trust between a Windows 10 PC on a Workgroup and another Domain?

Tags: windows-10, windows-domain

This is in a development environment:  Some developers are not on the domain -- they use their personal laptops, but they need to use some domain accounts locally.  For example, to set a local IIS application pool to run as a domain account so that it can access domain resources.  In choosing the app pool identity, you can't just specify DOMAIN\user.  The domain is not pickable from the Locations on the account selector.

So I am thinking if we can add a trust between the workgroup (or even better, the workstation) and the Domain so that the domain would show up as a location, that would solve the problem.

Is it possible to create this kind of trust or other relationship that would make the workstation at least know about the domain for the purpose of adding members to local groups and selecting users in other contexts?

Answer (score 1):

Trust relationships are based on domain or AD, so don't work for Workgroup.

The only solution I can see is to have some intermediate computer that is member
of the domain and that will intercede for the computers that are out of the domain.

As I don't know what the remote developers need, I cannot be more specific than that.